# Lamp cord (?) coming from ceiling light fixture box

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, ceiling

Looking for some assistance as I am not an electrician. I've replaced light fixtures and ceiling fans with no issues in the past, but have not seen something like this.

I removed a tube flourescent fixture from the ceiling to replace it with a new track light in our bathroom. There are also two recessed lights on this circuit in the soffit over the sinks.

The problem is that there appears to be a lamp cord in place of the neutral/white (?) wire. So what I see are the green ground wire, black live wire, and then this split wire cord.

I tried attaching both of the ends to the white wire from the new light, but only get a flicker when switched on. This lamp cord doesn't attach to the wall switch and runs into a metal conduit from the mounting box in the ceiling.

Any thoughts on what this setup is or how to make it work?

[image]

Comment: The obvious question is how was the old lamp connected?

Comment: My guess is someone ran out of proper wire and used what was handy.  Would need to find other end of lamp cord to see what is happening, how it is being used for.  Probably need to replace it for code.

Comment: The old fixture was a long two bulb fluorescent light fixture. I don't recall how it was connected, it's been a bit since I removed it. 

The wires go straight into a metal tube that's connected to the box so I can't see beyond that.

Comment: That lamp cord goes somewhere, my concern is if lamp cord was used they may have also buried the box where the other end of it is. If there's an outlet check it, remove the recessed lights and check there. If that lamp cord is in conduit it should be fairly easy to replace with correct wire. If you find the other end post a picture and you should get an answer as to how to connect the light properly.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no".  We can't guess where those wires go.  The box looks like it's incorrectly recessed more than 1/4" and the ceiling opening isn't even the right shape for the box.  This is not a professional rough in.

As the comments indicated, you would need to trace the conduit at least.

Comment: I'll take out the recessed lights and see if I can locate the other end. It's not at the switch. The previous owner of this house did some diy electrical work the keeps me up at night.